# .SlideDown not working on appended Html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't seem to get the `slideDown` effect to work when appending a `div`. The HTML and jQuery is below.
Any suggestions would be a great help. Thanks!

**HTML**

```
<div class="pin">
    <div class="top-pin">
        <img class="icon-pic" src="img/nautica.gif" />
        <p class= "pin-title">Nautica</p>
    </div>
    <img class="pin-pic" src="img/shoes.jpg" />
    <div class="pin-comment">
        <img class="small-icon-pic" src="img/Calvin_pic.png" />
        <p class="pin-comment-text">Can't go wrong with classic sperrys.     #topsiders</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var hiddenComments = "<div class='hidden-comment'><img class='small-icon-pic' src='img/Calvin_pic.png' /><p class='pin-comment-text'>Can't go wrong with classic sperrys. #topsiders</p></div>";

$(".comment-icon").click(function (event) {
    $('.pin-comment:last').append(hiddenComments);
    $('.pin-comment').find('.new-comment:last').slideDown('slow');
    $(this).parent().find(".comment-hidden").slideDown();
    $(this).parent().find(".comment-count").hide();
});
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the .comment-icon in your markup. Also, could you show the js in context? Is it inline in a script block right below the markup (not seeing a script block) or is it in an external file? If it's in an external file, where is it being pulled in?

Comment: I agree with Brian. We need the full context to debug.

Comment: the closing `div` for `.pin` was missing.

Comment: Is it *really* the `slideDown` not working on dynamic content, or is it (as I suspect) the whole `click` event handler not executing for dynamic content?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to include the animation as callback of the others, cause as I remember an animation will stop the others

Try this

```
$(".comment-icon").click(function (event) {
    $('.pin-comment:last').append(hiddenComments);
    $('.pin-comment').find('.new-comment:last').slideDown('slow', function(){
          $(this).parent().find(".comment-hidden").slideDown( function(){
              $(this).parent().find(".comment-count").hide();
          );
        );
    });
```

maybe you need to rearrange the jquery this selectors